# kendoUi grid, HTTPGET default

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.List)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Code);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
    })
    .Scrollable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetList", "Home").Data("additionalData")))
)

--javascript 
    function additionalData() {
        return { searchTerm: search }
    }
```

I have this simple kendoui grid, my problem is it is making httppost to the controller, i need to do http get.

is there any way i can modify this? to do httpget, i've read online that the default for the grid is post, but could not find anything on this to make it a get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the HTTP verb of any of your datasource action with the `Type` method on the [`CrudOperationBuilder` class](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/wrappers/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/CrudOperationBuilder#methods-Type%28System.Web.Mvc.HttpVerbs%29):

```
 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetList", "Home")
                          .Type(HttpVerbs.Get)
                          .Data("additionalData")))
```